# Getting Out of memory error in android Maps sometimes

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

In my app there is a main screen in which there is a mapview(more like a static image), on click of which it opens a screen which has a supportmapfragment with additional tile layers. This works fine on most of the devices, but only on some devices if I do navigate between the main screen and maps screen multiple times then I am getting out of memory exception. Any suggestions for this?

Logs :

```
W/Adreno-GSL(30734): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2461>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
E/Adreno-GSL(30734): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2236>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
```

Comment: Run LeakCanary and see if you have a memory leak.  Having it when navigating between screens multiple times makes me think you're leaking either the Activity or a large subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in your manifest file

```
android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: I already have these set in the manifest file, wouldn't solve the issue with this.

Comment: If you are using the image might be possible that the image is of high resolution. You have to resize the image then it will solve the problem of Out of memory error .